# Paillier Cryptosystem - Practical applications?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, paillier

I wonder: are there any real-world practical applications using the Paillier cryptosystem , as introduced in [1], or some derivations of it?

I'm aware of quite a few schemes proposed in literature how to use it for voting, zero-knowledge proofs and such, and also of many prototypical implementations online, but I can't seem to find any application where a Paillier(-based) scheme was effectively used...(also, I don't think there is any standard defining it).

[1] Paillier, Pascal (1999). "Public-Key Cryptosystems Based on Composite Degree Residuosity Classes". EUROCRYPT. Springer. pp. 223–238

Comment: Well many people use a variant/generalization called the Damgard-Jurik cryptosystem, so you might try searching for that as well.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, for example [CryptDB](https://css.csail.mit.edu/cryptdb/) uses the Paillier cryptosystem to implement homomorphic encryption for columns that require it. See [CryptDB: Protecting Confidentiality with
Encrypted Query Processing](http://people.csail.mit.edu/nickolai/papers/raluca-cryptdb.pdf) (pdf) for a description.

Whether you consider that use "effective" is another matter. Earlier this month there was [a back and forth](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/09/researchers-respond-to-developers-accusation-that-they-used-crypto-wrong/) between the CryptDB developers and some Microsoft researchers who claimed to have several attacks on CryptDB. However, as far as I can tell they were on the other forms of encryption CryptDB uses.